# Welcome screen displays on every boot

Tags: login, login-screen

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and on every boot, I am forced to create new user account, else, I won't be able to login to existing ones. After creating the user account, I'll have to switch to an existing user account to Access my files.

How can I solve this please.

Comment: Is the install CD / USB still in?

Comment: If you can't login, then how are you able to create a new user-account? What does exactly happen after boot? Please give us more details.

Comment: No, the CD/USB isn't still inserted. Besides, I did an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 via terminal.

Comment: You say Ubuntu, but you tagged Lubuntu. Which is it? Also, how did you upgrade to 20.04?

Comment: It's Ubuntu. I upgraded using the terminal. I got a prompt asking me to upgrade on my 18.04, which I obliged. Followed the instructions that came along, and I had my 20.04.